# Capitalize two letters after splitting the string into two words

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$name = ucfirst('kasiang');
```

I want to split it into two words and create `Ka Siang`

So what I tried:

```
echo substr_replace($name,' '.substr($name,2),2)
```

But i am getting only `Ka siang`. Is there any way to capitalize second letter too?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php, afterwards …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below.

```
<?php 

$name = ucfirst('kasiang');
echo substr_replace($name,' '.ucfirst(substr($name,2)),2);

?>
```

Another way is:

```
<?php 
echo ucwords(substr_replace($name,' '.substr($name,2),2));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), like comment above says:

```
<?php
$name = ucfirst('kasiang');

echo ucwords(substr_replace($name,' '.substr($name,2),2));
```

**Result:**

```
Ka Siang
```